# Can't compare Date portion of datetime field in ef / linq since updating .net/ef core to 6

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, linq, .net-6.0

I have a web API project previously using .net5 / ef 5.0.10 / Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL that I have been updating to .net 6 along with Ef core 6.0.5 / posgresql 6.0.4 packages.

This Method was fine before upgrade(s):

```
public List<HolidayDM> GetHolidays(DateTime date)
{
    IQueryable<HolidayDM> hols = _dbContext.Holiday.FindByCondition(x => x.Date.Date == date.Date);

    return hols.ToList();
}
```

But now throws error:
Npgsql.PostgresException : 42883: function date_trunc(unknown, timestamp with time zone, unknown) does not exist

It seems that a DateTime.Date comparison can't be done in the Linq anymore. It also doean't matter if I convert the date var to date.Date before passing it into the linq expression, the issue seems to be with x.Date.Date.
We have a lot of code that selects data from large datasets by the date. While I could change this simple example to:

```
var dayStart = date.Date;
var dayEnd = date.Date.AddDays(1);
IQueryable<HolidayDM> hols = _dbContext.Holiday.FindByCondition(x =>x.Date >= dayStart && x.Date <= dayEnd);
```

This isn't going to work in all (more complex) scenarios, neither is it as readable as the original. How do I go about this now? What am I missing?

Comment: Second one is the best solution. It uses indexes instead of `date_trunc`. Anyway create issue in EF Core Npgsql gitub.

Comment: The problem is the condition, not EF. Trying to filter based on a formula's result means no indexes can be used, forcing a full table scan. The equivalent expression `where x.DateField <= dayStart.Date && x.DateField< dayEnd.Date.AddDays(1)` will take advantage of indexes and be thousands of times faster. Same for the equality check

Comment: What is the type of the date field? PostgreSQL has a proper `date` type to store dates only.

Comment: The type of the date field is DateTime. I get that might result in a table scan, but there appears to be a regression in EF, what worked before now does not. I think I will raise an issue there.

Comment: https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2399